# attach a sheet to a mailid mentioned in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets-api

1. I have a spreadsheet with multiple sheets and I have another sheet with column A containing mail ids
   and column B containing sheet names.
2. Whenever a sheet comes I will check with relevant mail ids to where the sheets have to be attached
3. For eg for sheetname 10001515ADC I have to attach the sheet to mail id guru3291@gmail.com and mail it.
   Similarly for 10003810ADC the mail id is kumaraguru@aai.aero

The Code I worked on

```
 function email(){
 var heet= SpreadsheetApp.openById('1mbFTGxhvSbbttfkaezJpfU1TXNtJUPBvujREPi3yVwo');
 var mid = heet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 var getNames = mid.getDataRange().getValues();
 getNames.shift();
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheetsObj = {};
  for (var i = 1; i < sheets.length; i++) {
   sheetsObj[sheets[i].getSheetName()] = sheets[i];
   }
  Logger.log(sheetsObj);
 for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) {
  var r = getNames[i];
  if (r[1] in sheetsObj) {
  var ssID = ss.getId();
 Logger.log(ssID);
 var c =r[1];
 var p =ss.getSheetByName(c);
 p.activate;
 Logger.log(p);
 var sheetgId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
 Logger.log(sheetgId);
 var sheetName = ss.getName();
 Logger.log(sheetName);
 }
 var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

 var email = r[0];
 var subject = "Important Info!";
 var body = "Latest Recency Report \n\nRegards,\n VOTV-ATM-OPS";

 var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export?" + "format=xlsx" +  
 "&gid="+sheetgId+ "&portrait=true" + "&exportFormat=pdf";

 var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
 headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token}
 });
 var contents = result.getContent();
 MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".pdf", content:contents, 
 mimeType:"application//pdf"}]});
 }
 }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Your script is sending the wrong sheet because your `activate` request is not going through

This is due to the fact that you are referring to the method [activate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate) without calling it

- To call a method, you need to reference it including the `()` brackets
- So, modify `p.activate;` to `p.activate();`

See also [Fucniton invoacation in Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp).

SIDE NOTE

**You do not need to activate a sheet to work with it.**

The lines

```js
 var p =ss.getSheetByName(c);
 p.activate();
 var sheetgId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
```

can be replaced by

```js
 var p =ss.getSheetByName(c);
 var sheetgId = p.getSheetId();
```